# vQmod does not change the file at all (OpenCart)

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

So I'm trying to edit this file by adding some lines of code and commenting out something else. I created an xml file and added this:

```
<file name="catalog/view/theme/VARNA/template/common/VARNA_menu.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="before" offset="0"><![CDATA[
            if(($this->config->get('VARNAControl_status') == '1') && ( $this->config->get('VARNAControl_information_link') == '1')){    
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            $output .= '<li class="info_link top_cat"><a href="#">'."Features".'</a><ul class="children">';
            foreach ($features as $feature) {
                $output .= '<li class="subcat"><a href="'.$feature['href'].'">' . $feature['title'] . '</a></li>';
            }
            $output .= '</ul></li>';
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>

<file name="catalog/view/theme/VARNA/template/common/VARNA_menu.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="before" offset="0"><![CDATA[
            if(($this->config->get('VARNAControl_status') == '1') && ( $this->config->get('VARNAControl_information_link') == '1')){    
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            /*
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>

<file name="catalog/view/theme/VARNA/template/common/VARNA_menu.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="before" offset="0"><![CDATA[
            if(($this->config->get('VARNAControl_status') == '1') && ( $this->config->get('VARNAControl_custom_menu_1') != null)){
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            */
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

The first section is just to add, and the 2 bottom sections is to comment out another section of code already in the file. However, the changes does not get implemented.. I have plenty of other xml files that work without any issues, but for some reason, this particular one does nothing. If I manually change the file with the code I'm adding, it works fine.. Is there something wrong with my syntax here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is almost certainly due to whatever is including the custom file not running it through `VQMod::modCheck()`. You need to find where the files for `VARNA_menu.[php|tpl]` are being included/required and run them through `VQMod::modCheck()`, ensuring you pass the full path to the file

Comment: This was the issue indeed :) Thank you very much